# SQL SERVER 2008 how to use CONTAINSTABLE with 'ISAbout', 'AND','Weight(1.0)' Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have used the following, but giving error:-

```
SELECT  Main.Id,
        Main.Catid,
        Main.ParentId,
        Main.ARelation,
        Main.CRelation,
        Mytbl.RANK
FROM A as Main 
     INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (A,(ARelation,CRelation),'isabout("car*" and"mahindra*" weight(1.0))') as Mytbl
     ON Main.id=Mytbl.[KEY]
ORDER BY Mytbl.RANK DESC
```

**Error**

> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 28 Syntax error near 'and' in the full-text search condition 'isabout("Mahindra*" and "car*" weight(0.8))'.

Comment: Thanks for formatting :)

Comment: What error? This is just a query.

Comment: Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 28
Syntax error near 'and' in the full-text search condition 'isabout("Mahindra*" and "car*" weight(0.8))'.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189760%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) `ISABOUT` accepts a number of terms delimited by commas but does not allow combining them with `AND` or `OR`.

Try

```
CONTAINSTABLE (A,(ARelation,CRelation),'isabout("car*","mahindra*" weight(1.0))')
```